# Convert one item of a tuple in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list

I have this list of tuples:

```
b = [(1337345, 'xxx', '2016-05-18 18:44:26.0'),
     (1337346, 'yyy', '2016-05-18 18:44:35.0')]
```

What's the best to convert the date in each of the tuples into the datetime object using `datetime.strptime(my_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')`?

I can't directly modify the tuple so I assume this has to be done by building a new list? What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and build a new tuple with the formatted date:

```
[(tup[0], tup[1], datetime.strptime(tup[2], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') for tup in b]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension, unpack each tuple, and only do something to the third elements:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> b = [(1337345, 'xxx', '2016-05-18 18:44:26.0'),
...      (1337346, 'yyy', '2016-05-18 18:44:35.0')]
>>> [(first, second, datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')) for first, second, date in b]
[(1337345, 'xxx', datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 18, 18, 44, 26)), (1337346, 'yyy', datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 18, 18, 44, 35))]
```

In case you are using Python3.5 you can also do it like this:

```
>>> [(*head, datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')) for *head, date in b]
[(1337345, 'xxx', datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 18, 18, 44, 26)), (1337346, 'yyy', datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 18, 18, 44, 35))]
```

Comment: `_` and `__` are pretty weird names to use. The convention is to use those when you're not going to use the value, which you are.

Comment: @AlexHall I've come to agree.